# How can I open a pcap-ng file in C#

Tags: c#, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

Up to now I have been using WinPcap to open pcap files in C#:

```
[DllImport("wpcap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private extern static IntPtr pcap_open_offline(string fname, byte[] errbuf);
```

Now I want to do something similar to open pcap-ng files so I get nano-second resolution (I got a new sniffer :-) )

Unfortunately WinPcap fails with this error: "bad dump file format"

Anyone knows how to work with pcap-ng in Windows?

Cheers,
Pedro

Comment: Can you show more of you work for me? I need to read a .pcap file and read all the information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libpcap 1.1.x and later support reading some pcap-ng files (ones where all the interfaces have the same link-layer header type and snapshot length); however, there is no WinPcap release that's based on libpcap 1.1.x or 1.2.x, so there is no WinPcap release that can read pcap-ng files.  Thus, no CLR-language wrapper around WinPcap will be able to read pcap-ng files until such a WinPcap release comes out.

In addition, the libpcap/WinPcap API currently doesn't return time stamps with nanosecond resolution, so even if you did read a file with nanosecond-resolutions time stamp with libpcap, you wouldn't see nanosecond-resolution time stamps.

For now, you'd have to write your own code, or write a wrapper around Wireshark's Wiretap library.  (Note that Wiretap's API is subject to significant and incompatible changes from one Wireshark major release to another.)

Comment: Thanks Guy, that was the conclusion I arrived to. Do you know if they change Wiretap's API that often? I suppose at this time is fairly stable. I plan on using wtap_open_offline then I'll do my own parsing. (Also brilliant job in WinPcap, I have been a happy user many years).

Comment: If I have the time, I might change Wiretap's API quite significantly in Wireshark 1.8.0, to better support pcap-NG (and some other capture file formats).  I'd also like to find the time to add new APIs to libpcap to better handle pcap-NG; if so, hopefully WinPcap will be updated to that future version of libpcap.

Answer (score 4):

I've ported [WinPcap to libpcap 1.7.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpcap413-176/) and now it can open pcap-ng files and supports nanoseconds timestamp resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using sharpPcap? not sure if it supports it (can't try it right now), but it does support opening capture files as well iirc:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it doesn't support it.
CaptureFileReaderDevice throwed this:
    "Unable to open offline adapter: bad dump file format"

Comment: This isn't a product of SharpPcap however, the issue is that the version of libpcap/winpcap that you are using doesn't support pcap-ng format files yet. If the api remains the same but the support is added to libpcap/winpcap then SharpPcap will transparently gain the ability to use those pcap-ng files as it isn't actually doing any of the parsing itself, just interfacing with the lower level library (libpcap/winpcap).